# system.convert to custom object

Tags: c#, .net, typeconverter, xtragrid

we have a custom datatype object "Money" which is used to represent money values in our application. at the moment we are trying to implement some custom formatting within a grid component however the exception "InvalidCastException" is raised from System.Convert.

the text from the exception is;

```
System.InvalidCastException occurred
  Message="Invalid cast from 'System.Int32' to 'System.Money'."
  Source="mscorlib"
  StackTrace: at System.Convert.DefaultToType(IConvertible value, Type targetType, IFormatProvider provider)
  InnerException:
```

please note that our "Money" datatype does implement IConvertible as well as having its own TypeConverter.

How can we overcome this exception?

EDIT: This issue is related to DevExpress XtraGrid "Format Conditions" being evaluated on a column bound to our custom datatype "Money". The Money type can be bound to a column without problem, it only raises an InvalidCastException when a format condition is being evaluated on the column, i.e. GridColumnValue > 0

Comment: Did you really define your "Money" type as being in the "System" namespace, as the exception text shows?

Comment: Re your comment (my post), I think you need to update the question and tags; those points are *vital* to this question. I didn't want to edit myself as I'm not very familiar with those tools.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like the problem is that the *value* here is `int`, and `int` **isn't** convertible **to** `Money`, since it doesn't know anything about it (but `Money` *might* be convertible to `int`).

Glancing through the code (reflector), there is no obvious way that `Convert.ChangeType` is *ever* going to like this usage.

I'd be interested in knowing what grid component you are using, and where the `int` is coming from, because *normally* you would expect it to be dealing mainly to/from `string`, via the `TypeConverter` associated with the type or property (via `PropertyDescriptor.Converter`). Since it sounds like you have written your own `TypeConverter`, it would also be worth showing the `ConvertFrom` implementation.

*Outside* the grid usage, in regular C# you should be able to do this simply by define a static conversion operator (`implicit` / `explicit`).

Comment: thanks marc. to get specific, the grid component is DevExpress XtraGrid. We are attempting to implement a format condition based upon a column bound to our Money datatype. For example an expression such as "GridColumnPrice > 0" is raising the InvalidCastException in System.Convert. No matter what code we are implementing, i.e. TypeConverter or IConvertible none of these methods are being called to convert from Int32 to Money. We have static conversion operators in place, Int32 can be converted to Money using our conversion but the grid component is not calling them.

Comment: our TypeConverter implementation is used for string to Money and Money to string conversions. When we change/add code to detect an Int32 type, the code is still not being called by the grid.

Comment: So it sounds like the problem is the "`GridColumnPrice > 0`"; does it work OK if you remove this? You would have to check XtraGrid documentation to see how this behaves, as it is not a core component, but you could *try* implementing `IComparable<int>`, but I expect that is a bit overly hopeful.

Comment: everything works fine without the "GridColumnPrice > 0" expression. its only when the grid is attempting to evaluate the expression that it generates the InvalidCastException.

Comment: our Money type also implements IComparable<Money> and IComparable.